# How to stop fixed position of sticky sidebar when bottom footer is reached

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a pretty long sidebar that becomes fixed at a certain scroll position, but once it gets to the bottom of the page it overlaps the footer. I'd like to "unfix" the sidebar at this point, but not have it jump back up, because if i just remove the fixed class, it jumps up but if i scroll again at all it jumps back down. I'm very new to javascript still.

```
const staticSidebar = document.querySelector('.static-sidebar');
const navTop = staticSidebar.offsetTop;
const footerTop = document.querySelector('.footer').offsetTop;
console.log(`Footer top is ${footerTop}`);

function stickyNavigation() {
  if (window.scrollY >= navTop){
    staticSidebar.classList.add('fixed');   
  } else {
    staticSidebar.classList.remove('fixed');
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', stickyNavigation);
```

[codepen here](https://codepen.io/torch/pen/rgJZPa)

Comment: Have you looked into increasing the `z-index` of the footer to a higher value than the sticky sidebar? That should keep the sidebar still fixed but allow the content of the footer to render over it.

Comment: Yes, but if the content within the sidebar is longer then it will get cut off below the bottom of the window, and won't be able to scroll to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working how I want, only thing is there's a little bugginess to the sidebar getting stuck on top of the footer sometimes, but I'm happy with it overall. I'm setting top position to a negative number based on where the sidebar is relative to the footer.

```
function sticky_relocate() {
    const sticky = document.querySelector('#sticky');
    const window_top = window.scrollY;
    const footer_top = document.querySelector('#footer').offsetTop;
    const div_top = document.querySelector('#sticky-anchor').offsetTop;  
    const div_height = document.querySelector('#sticky').offsetHeight;
    var padding = 0;  // tweak here or get from margins etc

    if (window_top + div_height > footer_top - padding){
        let negTop = (window_top + div_height - footer_top + padding) * -1;
        sticky.style.top = negTop + 'px';
    }else if (window_top > div_top) {
        sticky.classList.add('stick');
        sticky.style.top = 0;
    } else {
        sticky.classList.remove('stick');  
    }
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', sticky_relocate);
```

[Updated pen](https://codepen.io/torch/pen/BgoZZo)